# Acumatica Purchase Order line GL account Sub un-editable

Tags: acumatica

For stock items, its not possible to edit the purchase order line level GL account and sub. Is this by design and if so what's the logic?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Account and Subaccount of a Purchase Order line are only editable for non-stock items and should be used to record purchased non-stock items that does not require receipt. For more details see [Acumatica Documentation](https://docref.acumatica.com/wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=5565686c-96c4-4bfa-a51d-9a2566baa808)